# coprocessor architecture from intel's xeon phi

Tags: architecture, parallel-processing, microprocessors, xeon-phi

I'm getting into the new xeon phi coprocessor world from intel.
I want to ask 2 questions, but close to each other.

First, pretty basic, what are the pros and cons compared to programming/cost/performance
against the gpu graphic cards.

Second, documentation says that coprocessors are connected through ring interconnection.
What other types of interconnection exist and how they work?
(a potential reference on instructive computer architechture would be very welcome).

Comment: This type of question is off-topic here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Pros: Heavier units ==> better branch handling. 
       Exceptional cache, better recursivity, easier code.
       Probably raytracer.
       AVX-512 compatible.
       System-bootable
       Emulates server operations. Could be good  for databases.

 Cons: Less pipelines mean less peak compute power .
       Power consumption. 
       Price.
```

Better try an opencl/c++amp example on this device. Then you can tell us how this works.
Maybe more advanced test is raytracing + storing results in a database.

Developer guide: [software architecture](http://www.intel.com.tr/content/www/tr/tr/processors/xeon/xeon-phi-coprocessor-system-software-developers-guide.html)

Microarchitecture: [silicon layout](http://www.intel.com.tr/content/www/tr/tr/processors/xeon/xeon-phi-coprocessor-datasheet.html)

Comment: thank you for the quick response. May I also ask for a reference on _computer architecture_? Since I'm not a computer scientist, I feel quite lost about this topic.

Comment: One of the most important pros is that it's x86 based which many people already know how to program.  But although AVX-512 is based on the Xeon Phi from what I have read it won't be 100% compatible.

Comment: Added some links from Intel's site. Im not computer scientist too but an high performance computing enthusiast.